# keys and values without quotes in an Array?

Tags: php

Help me understand this code :

```
Array
(
    [font-family] => font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    [font-name] => Abel
    [css-name] => Abel
)
```

from : http://phat-reaction.com/googlefonts.php .

Why there are no quotes around keys and values ? Is this valid php code ?

Comment: please check again the answers and accept the *right* one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why there are no quotes around keys and values ?

It is a dump of some array data in a format designed for a human to read, not code. See [print_r](http://php.net/print_r).

> Is this valid php code ?

No.

Comment: Any way to use this in php ?. I was thinking of using preg_replace to add qoutes around the values & keys .

Answer (score 0):

What you see here is an example of a dump, and not valid PHP. However, to answer your question about the quotations, you can look at the PHP documentation. For the keys, if you look in the PHP documentation, you will see it listed in the [don'ts](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts). But, as it says

> This is wrong, but it works. The reason is that this code has an
>   undefined constant (bar) rather than a string ('bar' - notice the quotes). PHP may in future define constants which, unfortunately for
>   such code, have the same name. It works because PHP automatically
>   converts a bare string (an unquoted string which does not correspond
>   to any known symbol) into a string which contains the bare string. For
>   instance, if there is no defined constant named bar, then PHP will
>   substitute in the string 'bar' and use that.

Values should always be contained in quotes, especially ones with spaces, since they will not be converted correctly using this deprecated format.

Comment: Yes i looked at that ;) . But in this case the values too are not surrounded in quotes , so i thought of asking it here . i am new to php .

Comment: Yeah, I updated it to include info about the values. The keys work but are not valid. The values are not valid and will not work, if only for the fact that they have spaces. But even if they didn't have spaces, this is not a practice you'd want to get into. In other words, quote your keys and values.

Comment: I realize it is not valid code, but in spite of that, as listed in the examples, it will work, except for the values which need to be in quotes. Which is why I corrected my post. I will update to clarify and state specifically that it is a dump, I guess, but I was answering the question, and addressing the example by linking to the documentation on the issue.